# Search result empty wordpress

Tags: search

I am trying to search any post by typing a related keyword but every times the result seems to be empty. Here is the link http://apprs.com/ripple/?s=music . I must say there is a post with the keyword i typed. Why isn't the search working. I checked the

```
 search.php and 
searchform.php.
```

Those seems all OK. I don't know what i am missing.

I will be feeling good if i could get any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the theme.. Its working now..